# What does "risks pivot upon ..." mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

I found this phrase in an academic paper and I am not quite sure what the authors meant:

> This  case  study  examines  the  implementation  of  the
> agile-system  approach  as  used  by  a  Small-to-Medium  Enterprise
> (SME)  software  developer. . . . The major conclusions from the case study are
> that a ‘default’ agile-system  approach  may  be  tailored  or
> fine-tuned  to  fit  an  individual  developer’s  software  process. . . . This
> tailoring,  however,  delivers a software development process that
> exhibits efficiencies and risks. . . . **The  risks  pivot
> upon  experience  levels,  skills  levels,  and  the  quality  of
> interaction  within  –  and  between  -  both  the  development  team
> and  customer organization.**

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Terry_Rowlands/publication/43509233_A_case_Study_of_SME_web_application_development_via_agile_methods/links/56c42a6f08aee3dcd4170c26/A-case-Study-of-SME-web-application-development-via-agile-methods.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=6KuI2hY2NqQLqVSMYAphjL2g8m-nF5DeIcU65oYPBrFEKWOYcHAlg_V9JhklEk1QtXKJ91eUhYkMcqiFQm4cPA.u6mVopBzf2_8nKuC0c8z4TRPFCqn2upDbxRLloBVvPQPLhfCYbNAAJYRwl8pMyp0WHKqSSw8lKLmQDMUsDIXIA&_sg%5B1%5D=A4wnGQ3XxArf8xV2iKqSiSmtNu0h66eU80gj_1ppoTygfaOuO4A9fX48gxerqnyqU3c3TCaqfCRdcfJEtzz4z8nSt7aGF4lT0vqfJ2FDSSGr.u6mVopBzf2_8nKuC0c8z4TRPFCqn2upDbxRLloBVvPQPLhfCYbNAAJYRwl8pMyp0WHKqSSw8lKLmQDMUsDIXIA&_sg%5B2%5D=YpcCSmlCTN2bQo1RcY5eCPtkaReTDJCUNwJY6gaW8T-i84HZA_VUI4Tq7jvmB9NEtXDcWwE8Lgy2uDE.g71JHb1yuRUUycuq15ZRdz6y5jMCsjPPxzQGaj2mJWX5SnLVYmZREeE5R14lG-y1-2KWL7p_DUnuYepxBQrToA&_sg%5B3%5D=qoyZ02tSuuRm8scIUE--XHXdX2EOdkGUFX8723sG5-OJ2EMpXtSlv-66Kdqz5aAjczqbLGYICWDhZfU.xkVNdASj0XwDZFZojRN4FK-XLP-PmcATDJtS6RTy_jkEMkcM2Fk0FvT_MPJhyzl32HkDq49bXAs0jFv19qD5Mg&_iepl=)

What does "the risks pivot upon" mean in this context? I searched Google for this phrase but could not find any useful. The phrase doesn't seem to be used often...

Could it mean something like "depend on" - e. g. "the risks are dependent on experience levels, skill levels, . . ."? Like high experience levels, skill levels, . . . would mitigate the risks?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this garnered two downvotes, however you may get somewhere looking up the phrase *pivot upon*.

Comment: To the downwoters: Please explain why you downvoted this question, so I can improve  my questions next time. Does it not belong here? Or wasn't it useful or clear?

Comment: You might have it better received on [ell.se] - it is clear to a native speaker what this means, I should think.

Comment: In answer to your question, yes—the writer is using "pivot upon" as the equivalent of "depend on" (or, more precisely, as the equivalent of "vary depending on"). "Pivot" isn't a great word choice here, and in general the excerpted language from the paper seems a bit self-consciously stiff and overwritten, but marcellothearcane is undoubtedly correct that most native English speakers who have some degree of familiarity with the peculiarities and excesses of academic writing would understand the writer's intended meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would have to search for the word "pivot" as opposed to "risks pivot upon" as the author is trying to bring attention to the three factors which are central to the "risks" of the tailored agile implementation.

You could say the three factors are connected to the risks of the implementation as a pivot (the three factors) around with an object (risks) moves.

Answer (score 0):

I read it, as you say, as "depends upon". It seems like a variant of "hinge upon", a hinge being a thing that pivots.